# атрибуты через css-суффикс в меню

Tags: jquery, joomla

для стилизации пункта меню потребовалось задать атрибут каждому пункту через настройку *css* класс ссылки. атрибут задаю таким образом:

```
" data-attr= "значение
```

этот код записываю прямо в поле *css* класс. в результате тег `a` принимает такой вид:

```
<a class="" data-attr="значение" href=...
```

все вроде хорошо и этот код даже является валидным.

но когда я добавляю такой атрибут, то *jquery* в событии `document ready` его не видети

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('[data-attr]').each(function(index) {
    alert('...');
  });
});
```

пробовал разными способами - даже проходил по всем ссылкам по всем необходимым мне классам... доходит даже до того что код `jQuery(".класс")` (класс указываю в том же поле *css* класс ссылки) не срабатывает, когда сразу после него указывается атрибут.

когда атрибут в этом поле не ставлю, то код срабатывает нормально. а между тем в странице *html*-код выглядит правильно.

подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: А значение из data-attr вы для чего хотите использовать?

Comment: для стилизации элемиента с помощью jquery (в моем случае замена текста другим способом сделать не удасться)..

Comment: Так может класс указать один для всех элементов с data-attr и перебор их делать по этому классу. А значение из data-attr получать через $(this).data('attr')?

Comment: в том и дело что уже всеми способами перепробовал в том числе и перебором по тегам (a), по атрибутам и по класам. возможно это связано именно с joomla. когда указываю в том поле просто класс то перебор по класам работает. когда указываю после него чтонибудь еще то перебор работать отказываеться. в том числе и при указании data-attr.

Comment: насчет click поторопился (коментарий удалил). короче делат обстоят так. если указан атрибут то даже при назначеном переборе на click по объекту он работать отказывается. теги все правильные. вот возможно чтото связано с dom ?? я в нем плохо разбераюсь. теоретически может быть такое чтовся строка из этого поля джумлойй автоматически записывается в память как клас хотя в коде страницы и записано верно??

Comment: Идей больше нет. Только если в консоль браузера посмотреть на наличие js ошибок. P.S. Если бы сайт с неработающим скриптом был доступен из инета, то можно было бы потыкать в него.

Comment: к сожалению он пока на локальном хосте.(

Answer (score 1):

разобрался в ситуации. не скажу, чтобы нашел решение -здесь думаю решение найдут более професиональые js-программисты. скорее понял почему возникает проблемма. в joomla есть некоторые компоненты при работе с которыми в поле css суффикс класса можно таким образом указать дополнительные параметры:

```
имя класса" имя параметра= "значение
```

и все будет реботать но видимо эти компоненты самостоятельно смотрят имя класа на предмет существующих в нем дополнительных параметров. в коде страницы впоследствии такие параметры могут находиться не сразу после имени класса , например так:

```
<img src = "..." class = "..." width = "..." height = "..." атрибут...>
```

у меня же в коде страницы имя атрибута идет сразу после имени класса:

```
<a class="" data-attr="значение" href=...
```

думаю что joomla не предусматривает этот вариант и без разбору берет всю строку из данного поля и записывает как имя класса.

в общем решил пойти другим путем. все равно этот параметр должен был содержать только числовые значения. добавлю в поле класс один класс используемый как флаг (по нему будем отбирать элементы) и второй класс с этим значением (пример: value123, value456, value789...) а потом регулярным выражением буду получать это значение из общей строки "attr("class")".

Если ктото в комментариях подскажет другой способ буду только рад..